# In CRM 2011, how to retrieve a Dialog guid by name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dialog, crm

We have Dynamics CRM 2011, rollup 16, on premises.

From javascript executing from a Contact form, I need to find the Guid of a Dialog by its **name**. I then launch that Dialog programmatically. My code works fine if I hardcode Guid, but now I want to generalize it so I don't have to worry which server I'm on, or which Dialog I need.

What are my choices, and what do you recommend and why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to build OData query to get records from Workflow entity (dialogs are there as well) by name.

Comment: Thanks for responding Andrii. Could you provide some specifics or a link?